Find Unity Editor 3D Coordinates On Mouse Click
I want to have it so you can place an object where you click your mouse when an "overview" camera is enabled but when left clicking nothing happens.
public void InputHandler()
{
    if (pickUpText.enabled)
    {
        // Handle picking up the box
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(pickUpKey))
        {
            overview.transform.position = cameraSpawnPosition;
            Destroy(box1);
            playerFirstPerson.enabled = false;
            overview.enabled = true;
            isOverviewCameraOn = true;
            Debug.Log(isOverviewCameraOn);
        }
    }
    
    if (isOverviewCameraOn)
    {
        Debug.Log("Overview camera is on, waiting for mouse click...");
        PlaceBox();
    }
}

    
private void PlaceBox()
{
    Debug.Log("Place Box Is On Waiting For Left Click");
    
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Debug.Log("Mouse Button Clicked!");

        Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;

        Ray ray = overview.ScreenPointToRay(mousePosition);

        Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 100f, Color.red, 1f);

        LayerMask layerMask = LayerMask.GetMask("Ground");

        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, layerMask))
        {
            Debug.Log("World Position: " + hit.point);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("No hit detected.");
        }

        spawnPlacedBox = new Vector3(hit.point.x, offsetY, hit.point.y);

        Instantiate(box2, spawnPlacedBox, Quaternion.identity);

        Debug.Log("Box Has Spawned!");
    }
}

I tried adding debug logs and changing some of the logic but nothing helped the issue. My code executes all the Debug Logs other than the ones under the if statement in the PlaceBox method; but does not do anything after. Could it be because I changed the camera? Also I do not get any errors in unity editor, it is just that what I am trying to do is not working.
Also sorry if my question was confusing. I am new to coding and stack overflow.

GetMouseButtonDown applies only in the single frame it occurs, so is best handled in update. So, in update you'd do if Input.getmousebuttondown do placebox - note your title bears no resemblance to the question

Could it be that playerFirstPerson.enabled = false; also prevents InputHandler from being called anymore? It's a bit hard to reproduce your issue without further context (see [mcve])

Are you calling InputHandler in an Update? I know you say you read those debug logs, but I want to make sure.
